# How to choose color in the section boxes of document class "sciposter"?

Tags: sectioning, color, posters, sciposter

I am using a poster template very similar to [this one](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/senac-poster-with-the-sciposter-package/jzsxddxcvncm). I like it, but I want to change the standard colour of the section boxes ("Resume", "Introduction" a.s.o.) to a more catchy colour, e.g. red. How can I do this? Tnx
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can view the sciposter manual with `texdoc sciposter` or at https://texdoc.org/serve/sciposter/0

section 5 shows the color settings, in particular

```
\definecolor{BoxCol}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,1}
```

is what sets the initial grey box behind section color